# How can I check if a 2d array contains an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Given a 2d array, for example

```
int[][] arr = { {2,3}, {53, 2}, {23,13} };
```

how can I check if it contains the array `{53, 2}`?

I have the following code:

```
int[][] arr = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {5, 2}, {5, 5},
                     {5, 8}, {6, 4}, {6, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 6}, {7, 9}, {8, 5}, {8, 8}, {9, 7}};
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        //here i want to check if arr contains the array {i, j} 
    }
}
```

How can this be done simply and efficiently?

Comment: Check for the first element of each row with the first element of searching row, if they are equal then loop through that row for the rest of the elements, when mismatch, repeat the process for rest of the rows.

Comment: Did you mean to say _contains the array `{i, j}`_, where i and j are the indices of the loops? Or did you mean a specific array like `{53, 2}`?

Answer (score 2):

If allowed by your Java version and your organization, you may use a stream pipeline:

```
    int[][] arr = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {5, 2}, {5, 5},
            {5, 8}, {6, 4}, {6, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 6}, {7, 9}, {8, 5}, {8, 8}, {9, 7}};
    int[] lineToSearchFor = { 8, 5 };
    boolean arrayContainsLine = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .anyMatch(line -> Arrays.equals(line, lineToSearchFor));
    System.out.println(arrayContainsLine);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> true

Streams can be used in Java 8 and later.

Comment: Really short, clean, and nice solution :thumbs_up:

Comment: Interesting downvote. Downvotes are part of life on Stack Overflow, that’s fine. I’m curious about the explanation for this one (the upvote has already been explained, and thanks).

Comment: I guess you can wait long for an explanation, this thread was a downvote mess from the start.

Comment: Thanks, @maio290, I will take that as at least a possible part of an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through the entire array, analyzing the values (based on the indexes) and comparing with the given tuple. Notice that `array.length` will give you the correct number of elements on the entire array, and `array[i].length` will also do the same, for a particular row identified by `i` so you don't need to handle (and change from time to time) the indexes and array size/length manually.

```java
public class Application {
  final static int[][] array = { YOUR_TUPLES_HERE };

  public static boolean contains(final int x, final int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i][0] == x) { // ...or just && array[i][array[i].length - 1] == y
        for (int j = array[i].length - 1; 0 < j; j--) {
          if (array[i][j] == y) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.printf("==> %s%n", contains(3, 1)); // true
    System.out.printf("==> %s%n", contains(6, 5)); // false
    System.out.printf("==> %s%n", contains(9, 9)); // false
  }
}
```

> You can just use `1` instead of `array[i].length` if you are sure the array never have more than two elements on the second dimension.

Alternatively, you can model `{ 1, 3 }` as, for instance, `Point(x, y)` and that would make your life easier, unless this is one of those class assignments (or some sort of exercise) you are not free to model stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code sample. May be is not the best one, but it is working.

```
int[][] arr = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {5, 2}, {5, 5},
    {5, 8}, {6, 4}, {6, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 6}, {7, 9}, {8, 5}, {8, 8}, {9, 7}};

    int[] search = new int[]{7, 3};
    boolean exist = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for (; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != search[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == arr[0].length && arr[i][j-1] == search[j-1]) {
            exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(exist);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Answer (score -2):

I tend to use [Arrays.deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) for such cases:

```
    String arrAsString = Arrays.deepToString(arr);
    if(arrAsString.contains("[53, 2]"))
    {
        System.out.println("contains line");
    }
```

Comment: Not my downvote. Although I don't think this is very efficient, especially if the array is very large and doesn't look very elegant, it does serve its purpose. KISS, keep it simple and stupid.

Comment: I guess the biggest advantage of this method is, that you could write it in one line (storing the string into an own variable is obviously not needed, unless you want to print the array) - but I agree, for big arrays, this might be not the best method.

Comment: Linear search through a large array (say, 1000 by 1000 or greater) will never be cheap. I wouldn’t expect the cost of this particular approach to prohibitive in very many situations, but you would have to make your own observations and measurements (not that this code would be my style).